# Cassandra, find details of second largest salary

Tags: database, cassandra

**I want to get the seocond largest salary **

```
select Max(Salary) from table;
```

Is there any word like skip in cassandra??

Comment: No, CQL does not have a way to skip rows in aggregations.

Comment: Also, I would advise against running that query without a `WHERE` clause filtering on the partition key.